# Assigning background color to classes from array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have six div's on a page that each have the same class. I am trying to assign each of them one unique color that I have chosen in an array. I don't want any of them to have the same color.

I've successfully assigned each of the divs a background color from an array, however, some of the classes can get the same background color since its currently just choosing the color randomly from the array.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".et_pb_post").each(function() {
  var colors = ["#CFEAEA ","#c9e3d5","#e7dadd","#dde9eb","#ecfac7","#facba9","#dfdbd3","#f1fdc1"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);    
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
});
```

and then the html is something like

```
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color A</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color B</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color C</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color D</div>
```

How do I make sure all of the background-colors are unique?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On way you can do this is to create a copy of the colors array and remove the color from it whenever it's picked for a div :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var colors = ["#CFEAEA ", "#c9e3d5", "#e7dadd", "#dde9eb", "#ecfac7", "#facba9", "#dfdbd3", "#f1fdc1"];

  var copy = [...colors];

  $(".et_pb_post").each(function() {

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", copy[rand]);

    copy = copy.filter(color => color !== copy[rand]);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color A</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color B</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color C</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color D</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first shuffle the array with the random values as described at

[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Then whenever you use a value from the array, you remove it from the array using `pop()` (or `shift()`).

That way you make sure every value from the array is only used once.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a group of elements from the dom, one for each div like this:

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByClassName("et_pb_post");
```

then you can loop thru and use the same loop counter as index in your bg color array to assign the property to each div element...

```
for (var i = 1; i < colors.length; i++)
{
    divElement[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

the key is using a single loop and index to coordinate between the two arrays, divs and colors.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the chosen color from the array of colors, so it can't be picked again. As a bonus I've removed jQuery for you.

```
// define colors
let colors = ["#CFEAEA", "#c9e3d5", "#e7dadd", "#dde9eb", "#ecfac7", "#facba9", "#dfdbd3", "#f1fdc1"];

// get all .et_pb_post elements and loop over 'em
document.querySelectorAll('.et_pb_post')
  .forEach((post) => {
    // get random color
    const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

    // set background color for current post
    post.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;

    // filter colors to remove randomColor from the array
    colors = colors.filter((color) => color !== randomColor);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var index = 0;
$(".et_pb_post").each(function(item) {
  var colors = ["#CFEAEA ","#c9e3d5","#e7dadd","#dde9eb","#ecfac7","#facba9","#dfdbd3","#f1fdc1"];
  var colorsLength = colors.length;
  var colorIndex = index%colorsLength;   
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[colorIndex]);
    index++;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color A</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color B</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color C</div>
<div class="et_pb_post">Some content with bg-color D</div>
```